# Attach email and reply in same thread to case using flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow, servicecloud

I have a requirement where I need to send the email using flow and want that to get  attach to the particular case. Also, If someone reply to that mail it also get attach to  that case only.

Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar kind of thing long time back using email template. I guess it will work for flow as well. You need to generate the reference id and attach in your email subject. Also, add that in your email body as well.

Ex ->
"Your subject" + "[ref:*" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" ) & ".*" & LEFT(Id,5) &LEFT( SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Id,11), "0", "" ),9) & ":ref]"

In the body at the last add -

"ref:*" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" ) & ".*" & LEFT(Id,5) &LEFT( SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Id,11), "0", "" ),9) & ":ref"

Comment: Thank you It worked for me

Comment: My auto-response email thread working correctly with this formula, in Email-to-case. But I have screen flow rendered on the public community page to create a case, in this scenario formula is not working so the email is not attaching to Case. Any idea, help.